# Rails 4 to 5 AR boolean deprecation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model wish contains the bellow method called by `before_validation` :

```
def set_to_false
  self.confirme ||= false
  self.deny ||= false
  self.favoris ||= false
  self.code_valid ||= false
end
```

When I run my tests, I got the deprecation message

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You attempted to assign a value which is not
>   explicitly `true` or `false` to a boolean column. Currently this value
>   casts to `false`. This will change to match Ruby's semantics, and will
>   cast to `true` in Rails 5. If you would like to maintain the current
>   behavior, you should explicitly handle the values you would like cast
>   to `false`. (called from cast_value at
>   ./Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/type/boolean.rb:17)

I understand I have to cast but I couldn't find a simple and smart way to do it. Any help to remove this deprecation would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple booleanification trick that I use often, double negation:

```
before_validation :booleanify

def booleanify
  self.confirm = !!confirm
  self.deny = !!deny
  ...
end
```

In case you are not familiar with this trick, it'll convert all values to their boolean equivalents, according to ruby rules (`nil` and `false` become `false`, everything else becomes `true`)

```
'foo' # => "foo"
!'foo' # => false
!!'foo' # => true

!nil # => true
!!nil # => false
```

Comment: I recommend using the `present?` in lieu of `!!` as it works for empty values as well, so `"".present?`, `[].present?`, `{}.present?` all return false.

Comment: @AnthonyE: it depends on concrete use case, but yeah, thanks for mentioning this!